# Cannot be resolved or is not a field (Processing)

Tags: java, class, arraylist, processing

I am doing a ray tracer in processing and I get an error on line

```
float xn = (this.r.direction.x) - (surface.center.x);
```

"surface.center cannot be resolved or is not a field"

This is my code.

```
//This is what I called in some other file
scene.surfaces.add(new Sphere(scene.material, center, r));

class Scene {
  private ArrayList<Light> lights;
  private ArrayList<Surface> surfaces;
  private Material material;
  Scene() {
    this.lights = new ArrayList<Light>();
    this.surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();
  }
  void setMaterial (Material m) {
    this.material = m;
  }
}

abstract class Surface {
  private Material m;
  Surface(Material m) {
    this.m = m;
  }
}

class Sphere extends Surface {
  private Vec3 center;
  float radius;

  Sphere(Material m, Vec3 center, float radius) {
    super(m);
    this.center = center;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}

class Hit {
private float time;
private Vec3 normal;
private Surface surface;
private Ray r;

Hit(Ray r, float t) {
  this.r = r;
  this.time = t;
  this.surface = scene.surfaces.get(0);

  float xn = (this.r.direction.x) - (surface.center.x); //ERORR
  float yn = (this.r.direction.y) - (surface.center.y);
  float zn = (this.r.direction.z) - (surface.center.z);

  Vec3 norm = new Vec3(xn, yn, zn);
  norm.normalize();

  this.normal = norm;
  }
}

class Vec3 {
  float x, y, x;
  //then constructor and some functions
}
```

I tried making a the ArrayList surfaces in public, I tried making a getter function, I tried changing the "ArrayList Surfaces" to "ArrayList Sphere" (the inside the smaller than greater than sign).

I have no idea why this isn't working. I suspect that it might be just Processing program's error, it's some what buggy.

Thanks!

Comment: The class `Surface` has no attribute `center`, therefore, `center` cannot be found. Your class `Sphere` does have a `center`, but not each `Surface` is a `Sphere`.

Comment: I have Surface which is abstract which has Sphere as one type and Triangle as another. I do not know if Surface inside Hit will be either Sphere or Triangle... Is this just not possible? Do I just need to create both  private Triangle tri; private Sphere sph; and leave one null and just use the other?

Comment: You should read some [tutorials on inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)...

Comment: [UML](http://i.imgur.com/llEdkkX.png) this is what I was given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you correctly what the issue is. Update the following declaration from

```
private Surface surface;
```

to

```
private Sphere surface;
```